# Combinatorics - Number of combinations when you know some of the numbers.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If you have a safety lock with 4 "fields" and numbers from 0-9 in each of them, the number of combinations possible in obviously $10^4$, but what if you know that exactly two of the numbers are 4? I thought this would be $10 * 10 * 9 * 9 = 8100$ but it turns out it's not (You don't know in which fields the two 4's appear).

The answer should be 486.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: *at least* two of the numbers are $4$ or *exactly* two of the numbers are $4$? Do not answer this with a comment, but with an edit of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

There is only *one* way to get a 4, but since you don't know the fields where the 4's appear, they can be in ${4\choose2}$ positions.

**PS**

I just saw that you have given the answer to be 486.

That means that there are **exactly** two 4's, so the other numbers have only 9 choices, hence

$$9\cdot9\cdot1\cdot1{4\choose 2} = 486$$

[ Of course, it can be simplified to $9\cdot9\cdot{4\choose2}$, but the full expression shows exactly what you did ]

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom42$ possibilities for the two numbers $4$ to be placed.

The placing of these numbers $4$ determines the placing of the remaining numbers.

Both numbers can take $9$ values.

So it remains to calculate:

> $\binom42\times9\times9$